# Create a shortcut keys in C# to open IE

Tags: c#

I am going to create a shortcut key (Ctrl+O) to open Internet explorer in C#. In case IE is open, a certain page will be open or get focused.

Comment: You forgot to ask question (it has question mark at the end of sentence usually).

Comment: so is it windows application ?

Comment: yes, this is a question 
I need to know how bring focus on a certain tab in IE?

Comment: yes ..it is a windows application